# Obtener IP y nombre de la máquina en GeneXus 15

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de poder obtener nombre y la IP de una máquina en GeneXus 15.

Resulta que quiero subir una plataforma a un servidor y que este funcione como un registro de asistencia. Y solo me falta obtener la IP y el nombre. Esto se dará mediante un LOGIN.

Actualmente trabajo con GeneXus 15 + Java Web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El nombre de la máquina cliente no se puede obtener en un ambiente *web*.

La dirección IP sí, usando el tipo de datos [`HttpRequest`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6933,HttpRequest%20data%20type,):

```
&ipAddress = &httpRequest.RemoteAddress
```

Según [la documentación (en inglés)](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7026,RemoteAddress%20Property,), devuelve la dirección IPv4 o IPv6 del cliente.

Comment: Gracias por el dato de la IP, pero no habría la manera de obtener El nombre de la máquina o la MAC ?, sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Que tal angel, es como lo dice @Marcos, al ser web no es posible acceder a ese tipo de información en el cliente (nombre del equipo, MAC) ya que no tienes acceso al ActiveX del mismo. Podrías probar con unas funciones con JS, pero me parece que medio medio funcionan y solo en IE. Te dejo el dato en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser